# How to make only a component as lazy loading with routing in angular within a module

Tags: angular

How to make only a component as lazy loading with routing within module but module has 4 components and one component should be lazy with routing in angular

Comment: Thanks for your respond , but here whatever the component i want to make a lazy load that is not associated with any other component .ie means there is no parent component ,it is only a independent  component within a module  ...Now how i can make my component as lazy load but it dont have any parent component

Answer (score 0):

You can lazy load a single component from its parent using `import()` like this

```
constructor(private vcref: ViewContainerRef, private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver){ }

async loadGreetComponent(){
    
    this.vcref.clear();
    const { GreetComponent } = await import('./greet.component');
    let greetcomp = this.vcref.createComponent(
      this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(GreetComponent)
    );
  
  }
```

Read this [article](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-lazy-load-component-angular#:%7E:text=To%20lazy%20load%20the%20component,inside%20an%20async%2Fawait%20function.&text=The%20above%20function%20first%20clears,be%20added%20in%20the%20container.) for a complete explanation

Another way to do it would be to move the component to a different module and lazy load this module only. Something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'lazy-load-me', loadChildren: () => 
    import('./lazyload/lazyload.module')
      .then(m => m.LazyloadModule) 
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond , but here whatever the component i want to make a lazy load that is not associated with any other component .ie means there is no parent component ,it is only a independent  component within a module  ...Now how i can make my component as lazy load but it dont have any parent component